# Как загрузить данные из MySql на страницу в зависимости от значения переменной js или localStorage?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

У меня в БД есть несколько таблиц и мне необходимо подгружать данные из разных таблиц в зависимости от той которую выбрал пользователь.
На странице есть несколько кнопок, если пользователь нажимает кнопку "5", то страница перезагружается и выводятся данные из таблицы с номером 5.
Пробовал при клике записывать в LocalStorage, потом аяксом передавать при загрузке страницы в PHP и там через условие выводить, но не получается, как буд то, выводится все раньше чем передает аякс.
Вот код php

```
$group_brs = $_POST['bgColor'];
// $group_brs = 331;

if ($group_brs == 331) {
    $table_pred = 'predmets_331';
    $table_brs = 'brs331';
    $table_stud = 'students_331';
};

if ($group_brs == 231) {
    $table_pred = 'predmets_231';
    $table_brs = 'brs231';
    $table_stud = 'students_231';
};

if ($group_brs == 431) {
    $table_pred = 'predmets_431';
    $table_brs = 'brs431';
    $table_stud = 'students_431';
};
```

Если прописываю значение переменной сразу в PHP, то все работает.

Comment: значит неправильно считываешь $_POST['bgColor']

Comment: может вы в форме не указали метод?

Comment: Метод указан POST
Через echo вывожу, все верно, значение в PHP получаю верное

Comment: Зачем записывать в `LocalStorage`? Тут главное уяснить - ты аяксом передаёшь данные на сервер, там PHP делает запрос в базу и формирует уже **готовую** страницу, которую отдаёт клиенту.

Comment: После загрузки страницы, на ней выполняются действия с перезагрузкой и после перезагрузки надо что бы опять подгружались данные из той же таблицы, а сейчас после перезагрузки данных нет, т.к. надо опять нажимать кнопку для отправки данных на сервер. Вот я и думал после нажатия на кнопку записывать информацию в LocalStorage и потом оттуда отправлять на сервер, но не получается.